# PHP: PDO global database variable?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, function, object

i've been coding php for quite a while now but i recently got into object oriented programming.

Before i used mysql_connect(),mysql_query() and all those functions but then i heard that PDO would be way better alternative.

I thought why not and watched a basic PDO video.

```
try {
    global $db;
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pw);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("ERROR: " . $e->getMessage());
}

print(gettype($db)."<br>");

function test() {
print(gettype($db));
}

test();
```

So the problem here is, i want to create a function so i can easily insert new items into my table. But i ran to this problem, my $db is not global. So i would have to re-connect to my database when using the function, but i can't do that, it would not be good at all.

So how can work around this problem?
Oh and the above code outputs:

```
object
Notice: Undefined variable: db in /home/vhosts/ollie.ceify.net/www/ip-bless/connect.php on line 25 NULL
```

Comment: Pass the variable to your function as a parameter. [Also, read up on variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 3):

Create a on object that holds a private PDO Object and define a public query method that accepts table name, column name, and value arguments and can be called repeatedly:

```
class DatabaseObject{
  private $db;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->createDB();
  }

  private function createDB() {
    $this->db = PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdatabase", 'username', 'password');
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  }

  public function insert($table, $column, $value) {
    try {
      $this->db->query(sprintf("
        INSERT INTO %s (%s)
        VALUES (%s)",
        $table, $column, $value));
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
      return $e->getMessage();
    }
  }
}

$db = new DatabaseObject();
$db->insert('table_name', 'column_name', 'value');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need use `global` to get the global variable too.

```
function test() {
  global $db;
  print(gettype($db));
}
```

Comment: With over 29k rep you should know better than to use `global` like that.

Comment: @Matt Of cause i know that, but you should let the op know how to use global variable in the function.

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree. You're promoting poor practice by doing that. It's equivalent to suggesting someone use `mysql_*` functions, and pass user input directly to queries.

Comment: @Matt Can you explain me why is better to pass the $db PDO object as parameter than get it like so "global $db"?

Comment: @boyd [This article explains a lot.](http://tomnomnom.com/posts/why-global-state-is-the-devil-and-how-to-avoid-using-it)

Comment: @Matt Before you know something is bad, you must first know how to use it, that's all. Experience comes from practice.

Comment: @Matt: Making a database handle global is not unreasonable in a web application. It's not perfect from a design perspective, but it's an acceptable compromise.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the variable to your function as a parameter.

```
function test($dbObj) {
    print(gettype($dbObj));
}
```

**OR**

You can place your functions inside an object and have `$db` as a member variable:

```
class myClass {
    public $db;

    public function __construct($dbObj) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function test() {
        print(gettype($this->db));
    }
}

$myVar = new myClass();
$myVar->test();
```

Comment: But if he has 100 functions with 5 parameters each?He needs to add 1 new parameter with this $db in each function?

Comment: @boyd that's the price of poor design. You don't fix a design flaw by adding more design flaws.

Comment: @xdazz I'm assuming you're referencing my omission of `public` from the function? Good catch. Fixed. Thx!

Comment: @Matt No, check your `__construct`.

Comment: @Matt That's even worse, If you have many objects, your database will just cry.

Comment: @Matt The normal design is to use DI.

Comment: @xdazz good point. Changed it to `static` and only initialize it once.

Comment: @xdazz DI would be valid. 100%.

Comment: @Matt You are still doing db connection every time, if you use static, you need to check it first. But you do know what is DI, do you?

Comment: @xdazz you have been helping a troll to make up an answer which he does not deserve to give. After all his tantrum and rants.

Comment: @Cory look at my history on SO and you'll see I'm no troll. I may be a little overzealous when defending best practices, but I admit when I'm wrong. xdazz has been helpful in helping me fix my mistakes, and for that I showed him the proper thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is defining a function for connecting to the database or getting the already available handle.

```
function dbHandle()
{
    global $dbh;
    if (is_resource($dbh)) return $dbh;
    return $dbh = new PDO(...); # All your DB credentials here.
}
```

...as a simple example, if you have a more complicated setup you can, for example, store this information in static members of a class.

Comment: Do not use `global` like that. It is very poor practice.

Comment: Over 6 years of experience. (Ten if you include college).

Comment: @Matt I see, zero evidence. Greetings.

Comment: [Here's someone else's opinion on the matter](http://tomnomnom.com/posts/why-global-state-is-the-devil-and-how-to-avoid-using-it).

Comment: Arrogance is not very becoming.

Comment: @Matt assuming that programmers are all inexperienced and cannot write good code is a fallacy. If you cannot write a good application by yourself, it is your problem. Please don’t go around misleading newbies with these stuff, authority fallacies, and by using weasel words. You look like a troll.

Comment: What did I write to make you think I assume that *"programmers are inexperienced and cannot write good code"*? Of what "weasel words" do  you speak? It is an accepted fact that global variables are inappropriate in most cases, *this* being one of those cases.

Comment: @Matt well, it is your opinion. If you cannot tolerate others thinking differently please move on. It is not well seen that arrogant attitude of imposing your opinion on others.

Comment: ***This is not my opinion. It is industry-accepted as true.***

Comment: OK. Explain to *me* why `global` is proper in this case, since you're so cocksure about it.

Comment: The same can be said of any poor design. The problem is when you realize that there are inherent problems with an overly simplistic design, and have to completely refactor an entire system due to one minor technical flaw. You cannot be this short-sighted when writing code.

Comment: What about a problem with a complicated design? would it be easier to fix? why? why do I need to begin a simple program with an already complicated design? you cannot be this short-sighted when thinking about a simple program.

Comment: @Matt But it *is* your opinion. While it's a good rule of thumb to avoid globals in general, there are situations where using a global *can* simplify your code. This is one of them. Note that this is predicated on understanding things like scope and what `global` actually does, as opposed to plugging it in to fix an immediate problem (which is always a bad idea). If you understand what it does and the potential risks of using it; sure, why not?

Comment: @NullUserException right, if it was a bad practice and *always* an undesirable feature. It would not exist to begin with.